# Как убрать "Г." в JavsScript

Tags: javascript, дата

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла некая проблемка, нужно убрать "Г." при выводе даты в js.

```
function getLocalYearMonth(d) {
    return d.toLocaleDateString(locale, {
        year: '2-digit',
        month: 'long'
    });
}
var nDate = new Date(year, month, 1);
var title = document.getElementById('c-title');
    title.innerHTML = getLocalYearMonth(nDate);
```

При выводе получается примерно так: "Апрель 18Г.", мне нужно чтобы выводило просто "Апрель 18".

Comment: а если month убрать из toLocaleDateString?

Comment: `getLocalYearMonth(+nDate)` - тут плюс лишний.

Comment: Немного не уточнил, мне нужно чтобы месяц тоже показывало, но без "г". К примеру Апрель 2018

Comment: + убрал, спасибо

Comment: Соственно кроме вариантов убирать вручную или формировать результат двумя вызовами ничего в голову не приходит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кроме двух вариантов костыля ничего в голову не приходит.
А заглавную букву можно потом сделать в css при помощи `text-transform: capitalize`.

```js
function getLocalYearMonth(d) {
  return d.toLocaleDateString("ru-RU", { month: 'long' }) + " " + 
         d.toLocaleDateString("ru-RU", { year: '2-digit' });
}

var nDate = new Date();
console.log(getLocalYearMonth(nDate));
```

```js
function getLocalYearMonth(d) {
  return d.toLocaleDateString("ru-RU", { month: 'long', year: '2-digit' })
          .replace(/\s*г\./, "");
}

var nDate = new Date();
console.log(getLocalYearMonth(nDate));
```

Comment: Супер, хоть на костыле, но работает, спасибо)

Comment: Но второй способ для Августа не подойдет, ахах)

Comment: @YavDen, исправил :)

Answer (score 2):

Просто `slice(0, -3)`.
Вернет строку с "отрезанными" тремя последними символами (в данном случае "_г.")

```js
function getLocalYearMonth(d) {
    return d.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', {
        year: '2-digit',
        month: 'long'
    }).slice(0, -3);
}

console.log(getLocalYearMonth(new Date()));
```

---

Варианты с капитализацией строки:

1. ```js
       function getLocalYearMonth(d) {
           let result = d.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', {
               year: '2-digit',
               month: 'long'
           });
           return result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1, -3); 
       }

       console.log(getLocalYearMonth(new Date()));
   ```
2. ```js
       function getLocalYearMonth(d) {
           let result = d.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', {
               year: '2-digit',
               month: 'long'
           }).slice(0, -3);
           return result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1); 
       }

       console.log(getLocalYearMonth(new Date()));
   ```
3. ```js
       function getLocalYearMonth(d) {
           let result = d.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', {
               year: '2-digit',
               month: 'long'
           }).split('');
           result[0] = result[0].toUpperCase(); 
           return result.slice(0, -3).join(''); 
       }

       console.log(getLocalYearMonth(new Date()));
   ```

Рекомендую первый.